# Is this network reload error?

Tags: awk, network-interface

I have an oracle Linux 6.8 that eht3 has IP but when reload the network service with root permission got these things:

> Shutting down interface eth3:                              [  OK  ]
>
> Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
>
> Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
>
> awk: cmd. line:1: $1 == "alias" && $2 == "eth0\" { alias = $3; } awk:
>
> cmd. line:1:                        ^ unterminated string Bringing up
>
> interface eth3:  Determining if ip address (blublublu) is already in use for device eth3...

What for is this awk command?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 to this same location and the problem resolved!!